# Error when trying to use class, says that the type or namespace cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, json.net

I've looked at many questions about this issue and most fixed by changing the applications target from Net 4.0 Client to just Net 4.0, mine is already like that, so that is not the issue. The situation is I just got Json.Net and I created a class, Customer, to use with it, the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CC
{
    public class Customer
    {
        private string location;

        public string Location
        {
            get { return location; }
            set { location = value; }
        }

        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        private int serviceTimeMin;

        public int ServiceTimeMin
        {
            get { return serviceTimeMin; }
            set { serviceTimeMin = value; }
        }

        public Customer()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and then within my pages codebehind I have the following code:

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.Location = txtCustomerAddress + ", " + txtCustomerCity + ", " + txtCustomerState + " " + txtCustomerZipcode;
            customer.Name = txtCustomerFirstName + " " + txtCustomerLastName;
            customer.ServiceTimeMin = 3;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
         }
```

It is in the same namespace and all, already checked that, and when I type it out it has no error, it's just when I build to debug that I get the following:

```
CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Customer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and the source points to the line:

```
Line 290:            Customer customer = new Customer();
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Just want to clarify, this is all in the same namespace and same project (assembly).

Answer (score 1):

Is the codebehind also in the `CC` namespace? Otherwise you need to add `using CC` to the top of the file.

The only other thing I can think of is, if `Customer` did not build correctly. Are there any other errors or warnings? This may be a side-effect error.

Comment: Are they in the same project? (Assembly)

Comment: Yes they are in the same project.

Comment: Hmm. Add that to your question. My answer is now irrelevant.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is, if `Customer` did not build correctly. Are there any other errors or warnings? This may be a side-effect error.

Comment: Yeah, I checked all these things and I did mention that it's the same name space, I'll add that they're in the same project, thanks. Also, there are no other errors or warnings; in fact, visual studio doesn't say anything about the matter. I also think it's a build issue because it only displays when I build and view in browser; the error does not show up in the visual studio error list...

Comment: @ChristopherBonilla - by chance are you confusing "same project" with "same solution"? In other words, how may projects are in your solution, i.e., a class library, a web project, etc...

Comment: @MetroSmurf - Nope, only one project in my solution

Comment: I'd suggest cleaning the solution and rebuilding: right-click solution>clean solution. And then rebuild. If the error continues, then I suspect there is an output issue with your assembly.

Comment: @MetroSmurf - Already did that multiple times, even closed out every file and then the program, I guess I'll try restarting my computer, just to see and also deploying it to the server to see if I still get the same issue...

Comment: This just helped me. A new class I added wasn't in the same namespace! Definitely worth checking

Answer (score 0):

Are you running tests, and do you have code coverage enabled? Sometimes when this is the case your project DLL will not be updated.

Comment: I am debugging (pressing the green "play" triangle in visual studio 2010). I have not changed any defaults, so unless if that is enabled by default, then I do not have it enabled, where could I find that in Visual Studio? Never mind, i just looked it up and i am not doing that kind of testing, just simple debugging.